# Outlook 2003: How to display my own messages in conversation view?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2003

When I select View->Arrange By->Conversation in Outlook 2003, the messages I sent myself are not shown in the message threads (unlike the conversation view in say, Gmail). To show my  own messages I have to go to the Sent Items folder, if not someone has replied to one of my messages and included my original text.

Is there a way to make my own messages visible in the conversation threads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I accomplish this as follows in Outlook 2007, i don't recall is 2003 has the Search Folder feature:

Create a Search Folder configured to look in the Inbox, its sub-folders as well as the Sent Mail folder for mail sent in the last 2 weeks. (I picked two weeks as there is some overhead in navigating in and out of this folder.)

This search folder can then be set as your starting folder and you can treat it like your Inbox, except it has awesome conversation view!

Comment: This should work, only problem is that I cannot figure out how to search for the last two weeks. Only the last 7 days is an option (which is too short), or "last month", but that does not include the days of the current month. I'll have to investigate this separately. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Using Outlook for Mac 2011, I simply do the following:

In *Preferences -> Composing*, check "*When sending messages, automatically Bcc myself*".

The previous suggestions unfortunately don't work on my version of Outlook: search folders do not seem to show results from my sent folder (choosing "Folder Is Sent Items" shows nothing), and I could not find the option "In folders other than the Inbox, save replies with original message"

Answer (score 1):

If you have Outlook 2010 or newer by now, you can go to the View tab and select *Conversation Settings > Show Messages from Other Folders*.

This will include messages from the Sent Items folder in the thread view.

Comment: Does anyone know if this also applies to the Mac? If so, then please add an answer with a screenshot to [Show messages from other folders in conversation view on Outlook for Mac 2011](http://superuser.com/questions/491517/show-messages-from-other-folders-in-conversation-view-on-outlook-for-mac-2011).

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't been able to find any way to do this on Mac. The Mac Outlook app seems wayyy more bare-bones, sadly.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to look in your "sent" folder.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to have your sent replies stored in the same folder as the messages you replied to.

First, create a folder and set up a rule to have incoming messages stored in that folder.

Then, go to: Tools / Options / Preferences (tab) / E-mail Options (button) / Advanced E-mail Options (button) and check the "In folders other than the Inbox, save replies with original message".

Unfortunately, that will not take care of sent messages that are not replies, but you can create a rule for sent messages to save them in that folder as well, or move them manually.

Answer (score 0):

If you can write a rule which copies your sent emails to the inbox you can see your sent mails on top.

The downside of this approach is you'll see all emails sent by you, even though it's not a part of a conversation.

[image]