# Show messages from other folders in conversation view on Outlook for Mac 2011

Tags: macos, office-for-mac, microsoft-outlook-2011

On Outlook 2010 it is possible to show messages from other folders in the conversation view (it's an option in the Conversation Settings menu on the ribbon).

Is there a similar option for Outlook for Mac 2011?

Comment: Strange, because this MS article explicitly says it's possible, but just not *how*: https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/Outlook-for-Mac-2011-Best-Practices-Frequently-asked-questions-8cdb8110-6760-4d19-90cf-97848c43ada7 In Outlook For Mac (15.6) if you show messages in Conversation mode, and click on the conversation heading, then the reading pane shows *all* messages in conversation, including your replies from your Sent folder etc. I still don't see how to make my Sent messages show up in the main inbox

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this chart](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2397.outlook-outlook-for-mac-and-entourage-version-and-features-comparison-chart.aspx), it isn't possible in Outlook for Mac 2011.

[image]

Comment: Seems like it's still not possible as of Outlook 15 for Mac :-(

Comment: FYI, still not implemented with 16.8 for MacOS:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/lack-of-combined-inbox-in-outlook-365/33d2241f-b85a-4059-b6b1-9ca99410e6a2

Comment: Hi! I found a workaround for this annoying bug, which I replied in the thread about the same issue on Outlook 2016, which is still not fixed: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/388918/55194