# How to switch on Conversations view for every single folder at once in MS Outlook for Mac?

Tags: macos, microsoft-outlook

2021;

At work, I've been using Outlook on the web (http://outlook.office.com) for a while now, but we've been recently switchted to MacOS, so I started using the native Outlook client again:

Microsoft Outlook for Mac: Version 16.47 (21031401)

However, I found it annoying that every single folder (I already have) in my mailbox is not showing conversations by default. Same with newly created folders. And there doesn't seem to have any setting to change that, only for each folder... How can I change all at once? Or just complain...?

The question seems to have been posted almost a decade ago... [Show messages from other folders in conversation view on Outlook for Mac 2011](https://superuser.com/questions/491517/show-messages-from-other-folders-in-conversation-view-on-outlook-for-mac-2011) but does it count as a duplicate...?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the ***New Outlook for Mac***? [image]

According to my experience, we could set all folder(including new folders) with conversation view there

[image]

Comment: hello @Jade thanks for your answer; I would be glad to test this "New Outlook for Mac", but I can't see anywhere this switch your showing. Any idea how to get it?

Comment: OK found https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/the-new-outlook-for-mac-6283be54-e74d-434e-babb-b70cefc77439 and while I'm on BigSur 11.2.3 with Outlook 16.47 as told above I might be blocked by some other requirements, or even our IT team has blocked the availability of this "New Outlook"; will ask them soon...

Comment: Do you have any update now?